# Updating part of sqlite3 table using variables

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

ulogin=str(self.t1.get())
        med=str(self.mymed.get("1.0",END))
        print(med)

```
    conn = connect("med.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE user_details SET reminder ="+ med +"WHERE username =" + ulogin)
    conn.commit
    conn.close()
```

im trying to get this to update a text wall however it breaks continuously
line 284 on GitHub
link: https://github.com/Polar001/medicine-reminder/commit/0f6e74a1103937a24c67af3e8f07a2bcf0975f0a
if possible be as basic as possible im not good at coding at all

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is incorrectly constructed, use placeholder as below:

```
c.execute("UPDATE user_details SET reminder = ? WHERE username = ?", (med, ulogin))
```

Comment: Yes, it's updating the database however it doesn't appear to be updating it correctly. so when you sign in change the text in the Tkinter box and logout it's meant to update the existing string to the new string however it doesn't. it stays exactly the same.